# Having issues getting the notification feed for new follows when using stream-laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3, feed, getstream-io

I am building a small project using [Getstream](https://getstream.io/) Laravel package. However I am having a problem trying to display notifications for new followers. I get an empty result set when I call `\FeedManager::getNotificationFeed($request->user()->id)->getActivities()` in a controller method. I have my `follow` model looking like this:

```
class Follow extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['target_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function target()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function activityNotify()
    {
        $targetFeed = \FeedManager::getNotificationFeed($this->target->id);
        return array($targetFeed);
    }
}
```

Then the controller action to get the notifications for new follows looks like this:

```
public function notification(Request $request)
{
    $feed = \FeedManager::getNotificationFeed($request->user()->id);
    dd($feed->getActivities());
    $activities = $feed->getActivities(0,25)['results'];


    return view('feed.notifications', [
        'activities' => $activities,
    ]);
}
```

In the user model I have defined a relationship that a user has many follows. And lastly the follow and unfollow actions in the `FollowController` look like this:

```
public function follow(Request $request)
{
    // Create a new follow instance for the authenticated user
    // This target_id will come from a hidden field input after clicking the
    // follow button
    $request->user()->follows()->create([
        'target_id' => $request->target_id,
    ]);

    \FeedManager::followUser($request->user()->id, $request->target_id);

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function unfollow($user_id, Request $request)
{
    $follow = $request->user()->follows()->where('target_id', $user_id)->first();

    \FeedManager::unfollowUser($request->user()->id, $follow->target_id);

    $follow->delete();

   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Not sure if there's something I left out but I can't get results for the notification feed. If I head over to the explorer tab from the Stream dashboard, I can see that I got two new follows which generated both timeline and timeline_aggregated type of feed. Or how should I get the notification feed from a controller action? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\FeedManager::followUser` method create a two follow relationships: timeline to user and timeline_aggregated to user.

In this case what you want to create a follow relationship between notification and user. Something like this should do it:

```
\FeedManager:: getNotificationFeed($request->user()->id)
    .followFeed('user', $follow->target_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Ok I did try this approach but if I set `notification` as the target feed slug, I get an error: {"target": ["You can only follow flat feeds, not feeds of type notification"]}.  Also just to make sure I am on the right path, the line of code to establish the follow relationship goes inside the follow method in the controller right?

Comment: @ChristopherVundi sorry I wrote the request the way around

Comment: Hey updated the line of code you shared. Placed it inside the `follow` method in the `FollowController`. But calling `\FeedManager::getNotificationFeed($request->user()->id)->getActivities()` from the `notification` method inside the `FeedsController` brings back an empty results set. Is there anything I could be doing wrong. My code is exactly as it is above.

Comment: did you verify the follow relationships are created looking at Stream Dashboard?

Comment: Yeah, from the dashboard things are updated. If I go to `follows` for feed `(user I just followed)`, I can see timeline, timeline_aggregated, and notification feed under the followers section.

Comment: Just realized I was not importing the `\GetStream\StreamLaravel\Eloquent\ActivityTrait` in my Follow model. But things work fine now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ChristopherVundi can you mark the answer as correct or let me know what I should change?